# there was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm tring to get access to the data from another server using an API, but I'm getting an error.

web.config Client-Tag:

```
  <endpoint address="http://api.domain.co.za/FTIntegration.svc/BalanceLookup" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MembershipSoap" contract="FTFeverTreeWebService.IFTIntegration" name="MembershipSoap" />
```

web.config Binding-Tag:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap" />
    <binding name="MembershipSoap" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="4000000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The error comes from this line of code:

`FTFeverTreeWebService.Result_BalanceLookup blR = ft.BalanceLookup(bl);`

My whole code:

```
FeverTreeResponse response = new FeverTreeResponse();

try
{
    FTFeverTreeWebService.BalanceLookup bl = new FTFeverTreeWebService.BalanceLookup { BalanceID = request.BalanceID, CardOrIDNumber = request.CardOrIDNumber };

    FTFeverTreeWebService.FTIntegrationClient ft = new FTFeverTreeWebService.FTIntegrationClient();
    FTFeverTreeWebService.Result_BalanceLookup blR = ft.BalanceLookup(bl);

    response.Facility = blR.Facility;
    response.Name = blR.Name;
    response.Available = blR.Available;
    response.Success = blR.Success;
    response.Message = blR.Message;
    response.CardOrIDNumber = blR.CardOrIDNumber;
    response.InternalReference = blR.InternalReference;

}
catch (ValidationException e)
{

    response.Success = false;
    response.Message = e.ValidationResult.ErrorMessage;
    //response.DebugMessage = e.StackTrace;
}
return response;
```

Comment: Is the end point reachable? Could be your network might be blocking it, like a firewall rule or something.

Comment: Yeah, try to hit the endpoint with a browser.

Comment: when i ping the domain 'http://api.domain.co.za' it does come with result but the full address does not connect